# C# wrapper for DCMTK library using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, swig, dicom

I want to create C# wrapper for [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) library (which is written in C++) using SWIG. I have full source code of [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en), but I have one problem I can't solve...

My script for SWIG looks like this:

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_SWIG_I
# define WRAPPER_SWIG_I
%{ 
%}

%include "include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg/ddpiimpl.h"
%include "include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg/dipijpeg.h"
%include "include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg/djcodecd.h"
#endif
```

Then I run SWIG from command line:

```
swig -includeall -Wall -c++ -csharp -outdir $(SolutionDir)\dcmjpegcsharp\ -module dcmjpeg -namespace dcmjpeg dcmjpeg.i
```

... and it throws many errors that it is unable to find headers files (which are included inside these listed in the script). For example, header file "include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg/ddpiimpl.h" is including file "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h" which is in completely different location.

The problem is that the C++ headers files in [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) library's source code are scattered across multiple folders, and they "don't see each other". 
Is there a simple solution for that? Maybe to force SWIG to automatically and recursively search for headers files in some root directory of DCMTK source?

Comment: Generally I'd suggest avoiding the includeall option to SWIG if possible. You can use -I to set the search path if you need to, in the same way you would with GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Also, check out [FO-DICOM](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom) (formerly mDCM), and the ClearCanvas API (built on mDCM). I've found them much easier to work with than DCMTk wrapped for C#.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked specifically about DCMTK, so there could be very good reasons for that choice, however this info may be useful for you or others:

The other major Dicom tookit ([GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net)) already has a C# wrapper, created using SWIG. GDCM is a mature Dicom library used in large products for Dicom IO, e.g. [ITK](http://itk.org/)..